# no matching function to call for "getline"

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ programming. In a tutorial, the author mentioned "cin" will break if it reads a space in a string. If you want the program to read in an entire line of string with spaces, you should use the function "getline".

However, I couldn't make it work.

Here are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string my_name;

    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, my_name, "\n");

    cout << "My name is " << my_name << " .";
}
```

The IDE I am using is Xcode. The error message is "No matching function to call to 'getline'".

I have searched for similar issues but it seems to me none of the solutions apply to my problem. Maybe I am missing some knowledge? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What your teacher said is not true. `cin` will not "break". It's just that formatted extraction into an `std::string` is designed to read word by word. That's intentional. It's not broken.

As for your error, your call to `std::getline` is broken because the delimiter argument has the wrong type. `'\n'` is a `char` literal; `"\n"` is a `char` array literal, not at all what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation about the difference between '\n' and "\n"!

Comment: @NoahSong: It's not "an additional explanation"; it's the root cause of your problem!

Answer (score 15):

The **complete** error would tell you why your third parameter is of the wrong type.

It should be a character type, not a null-terminated string of characters.

```
getline(cin, my_name, '\n');
```

***Edit***: And,  `'\n'` *specifically* is the assumed delimiter in another form of `getline`:

```
getline(cin, my_name);
```

Comment: `getline(cin, my_name);` would be even better

Answer (score 1):

add this line work for me

```
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, and neither did the #include <string>

Comment: Just kidding, I found out that it's because of how I declared my file. I declared it as an "ofstream" instead of an "fstream" ahhaha

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to a char array you can use:

```
cin.getline(my_name, val_max);
```

Just make sure your buffer (val_max) is large enough